# Error when initialising CLPlacemark in objc func

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following tap handling function.

```
@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .ended:
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: mapView)
        let coordinate = mapView.convert(tapLocation, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        var tapLocationPlacemark = CLPlacemark()
        //rest of code is irrelevant
    default: break
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I'm initialising the variable `var tapLocationPlacemark = CLPlacemark()` within the function, clicking somewhere produces an EXC_BAD_ACCES error at the end of the function, however, if I declare it without initialisation (`var tapLocationPlacemark: CLPlacemark`) or I declare and initialise it as a global variable, the error is gone.

I imported CoreLocation at the beginning of the file and according to Objective-C documentation, the CLPlacemark exists also in Objective-C, so what could be the problem?

Error detailed description:

> Printing description of tapLocationPlacemark:
>   expression produced error: error: /var/folders/z6/3w15l2r93vvf0237nsdxkhr80000gn/T/expr14-98259a..swift:1:65: error: use of undeclared type 'CoreLocation'
>   Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer(bitPattern: 0x1290543a0)!.pointee)

Comment: is corelocation added in linked binaries section?

Comment: @Priyal I added it now, still getting the error